# Schrödinger-Propagator for combined linear and harmonic potential

Tags: homework-and-exercises, schroedinger-equation, potential-energy, harmonic-oscillator, propagator

Given the Hamiltonian
\begin{equation}
H = \frac{p^2}{2m} + V(x)
\end{equation}
The propagator for a pure harmonic potential of the form
\begin{equation}
V(x) = \frac{1}{2} m \omega^2 x^2
\end{equation}
is given in the wikipedia article about propagators https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagator.

My Question is: What is the propagator if the potential also contains a linear part?
For example:
\begin{equation}
V(x) = u_1 x + \frac{1}{2} m \omega^2 x^2.
\end{equation}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite that as
$$V(x) = \frac{1}{2}m\omega^2x^2 + u_1x = \left(\sqrt\frac{m\omega^2}{2}x+\frac{u_1}{2}\sqrt\frac{2}{m\omega^2}\right)^2 - \frac{u_1}{2m\omega^2}.$$

Then make a coordinate transformation to $\tilde{x} = \sqrt\frac{m\omega^2}{2}x+\frac{u_1}{2}\sqrt\frac{2}{m\omega^2}$ and write the momentum operator in this coordinate frame. All that changes are some prefactors.

EDIT: Sorry, probably better if you write it like that
$$V(x) = \frac{m\omega^2}{2}\left(x^2+\frac{2u_1}{m\omega^2}x\right) = \frac{m\omega^2}{2}\left(x+\frac{u_1}{m\omega^2}\right)^2-\frac{u_1^2}{2m\omega^2}$$
and $\tilde{x} = x+\frac{u_1}{m\omega^2}$, such that
$$V(\tilde{x}) = \frac{m\omega^2}{2}\tilde{x}^2.$$

Comment: Do you mind adding the resulting propagator to your response? The one which can be applied to the wavefunction in the original coordinate frame? I tried your approach but for me in the limit $\omega \to 0$ I could not reproduce the propagator for the linear potential only.

Comment: It's not obvious to me that you should just get to that expression upon taking the limit at the very end. If you take this limit for the propagator of the QHO you also don't arrive at the free particle propagator. The transformation I proposed doesn't make sense when $\omega = 0$.

Comment: but you should, right?

Comment: As I wrote in my comment above, doing so for the QHO propagator does not give the free particle propagator, so I don't think so.

Comment: I would say it does, if I take the limit $\omega \to 0$ of the QHO I get the free particle propagator...

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, yes you are of course right. But still, in the coordinate transformation we divide by $\omega$, so I would say you have to take this limit before the transformation, i.e. you start with $H = p^2/2m + u_1x$.